# How to determine size (in bytes) of a PyTables array?

Tags: python, scientific-computing, pytables

How can I determine the size (in bytes) of a PyTables Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that since all PyTables arrays are simply Numpy arrays underneath, you can do the following:

MyPytableFile.root.myPytableArray[:].nbytes

Answer (score 1):

Its not straight forward to do, but one thing you can do is to pickle the object and then determine the size of the serialized object. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563840/how-can-i-check-the-memory-usage-of-objects-in-ipython/565382#565382)

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
arrSizeInBytes = arr.nrows * arr.rowsize
```

At least it equals to the results of

```
./h5ls -r -v pytables.db | grep "Dataset\|Storage"
```