# Troubleshooting 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, django

I'm using `itertools.chain` method in Python to chain several Django `Querysets` together. By doing so, I'm not touching the database and this is the efficient behaviour I need. However, I'm using a third-party library to paginate these results and this library only accepts list and queryset objects. When calling it with the chain object I get the following error:

```
Exception Value: 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The line in the library ([django-pagemore](https://github.com/pennersr/django-pagemore/blob/master/pagemore/templatetags/pagemore.py#L106)) that is actually diving me crazy is:

```
objects = self.objects[page0*self.per_page:1+page*self.per_page]
```

**The problem here is that when using a chain you can't slice it.**

I know that I could convert the chain object into a list easily with `list()` method, but this would evaluate the ENTIRE queryset and this can contain thousands of items inside.

After some research on [how to calculate the size of a Python object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/565382/955619) 
I did some testing and using `sys.getsizeof(cPickle.dumps(content))` (where `content` is one of the objects inside the chain) gives me a value of `15,915 bytes`, so a chain containing 3,000 of these objects would need `45.53 MB` aprox!

Comment: `sys.getsizeof()` of the string produced by pickling is not a very good indicator of size, btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`itertools.chain()` returns a *iterable*, not a sequence. You cannot index or slice an iterable.

Use [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to define a subset; when looping over the `islice()` result, the underlying iterable will be advanced to the starting index, then will yield items until the end index:

```
objects = islice(self.objects, page0 * self.per_page, 1 + page * self.per_page)
```

This *iterates* over the chained sequence, so you cannot then access the items before the `start` index.

Comment: Note that this also consumes part or all of the iterable as well.

Comment: @Caumons: Then you are slicing a chain that doesn't return enough objects, I suspect. It works just fine for me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK, the problem was that I was iterating over the chain object before calling `islice()` to it, so the pointer was at the end of the iterable. However, I'm wondering if modifying the library will have side effects because `isslice()` will actually shorten the chain each time and when a chain is iterated, then trying to iterate it again will do nothing. I've tried to do a `deepcopy()` of the chain but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Caumons: That is the nature of an iterator. You **cannot** rewind them or iterate more than once. If you need random access to the items, then you are *forced* to use a list. That, or *recreate* the iterator (call `chain()` on the queries again).

Comment: @Caumons: TLDR: you cannot iterate over an iterator more than once.

Comment: So, if I'm forced to use a list... Which is a better way to calculate the memory used than the method I used? And another thing: working with a 50 MB list would cause problems to a webserver, I mean, is it a terribly huge object in memory that MUST be avoided?

Comment: You are trading memory vs database bandwidth here, btw. The chain is based on a database query, so recreating the chain for a second run-through results in a new series of database queries plus data transfer from database to web server process. loading everything into memory *may* be faster, and memory is cheap.

Comment: You'll need to recursively call `sys.getsizeof()` on the content object and it's attributes to calculate the memory size. Calling `sys.getsizeof()` on a pickle string only tells you how much memory that *string* takes, and a pickle is not necessarily a good way of representing how much memory the original object requires because a pickle needs to be importable cross-platform.

Comment: A Python integer on a 64-bit machine takes more memory than on a 32-bit machine, but the pickle for that integer is *the same size* on either. And if pickle *were* a reasonable representation of a memory footprint, then just using the `len()` of the string would be much better to measure the size..

Comment: Sounds like you could benefit from using a sparse list filled only with the objects of the page, fooling the third-party library into retrieving from an almost-empty list. One example is the blist [http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/blist.html].

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for your comments! I'll take into account what you told me about measuring an object's memory size. (Maybe you want to add a better response to the linked question). Finally, to solve the problem I simply limited the query and used `list()` in conjuction with `chain()`, as it's the simplest approach I can think of. It may be considered quick & dirty, but at least it will work (I hope). I've accepted your answer because you explained me how to slice a chain! Thanks :)